# Websocket is working but client wont connect

Tags: php, websocket

I've been working on this simple websocket tutorial from the guys over at tuts+
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

I copied the code over and only changed 3 lines of code (changed the port number).

```
var host = "ws://localhost:8000/socket/server/startDaemon.php"; //from client.php

$WebSocket = new socketWebSocket('localhost',8000); //from startDaemon.php

public function __construct($host='localhost',$port=8000,$max=100) //from socket.class.php
```

I have all these files in one folder on a linode server and all I get is "Socket Status: 3 (Closed)". You can see the client.php here
http://ckfrantz.com/arena/client.php

I appreciate your time.